# Trouble with shape append on VB6

Tags: vba, vb6

I'm working on VB6 and I try to create an report, for create this report I'm using shape with 3 levels.

```
"SHAPE APPEND " & _
    "  New adVarChar(15) As zoneId," & _
    "  New adVarChar(15) As zoneNam," & _
        "  ((SHAPE APPEND " & _
            "  New adVarChar(30) As ID, New adVarChar(30) As costumerName," & _
           "  ((SHAPE APPEND " & _
                "  New adVarChar(15) As productCode, New adVarChar(25) As produtName, New product(30) As product," & _
                "  New adVarChar(30) As price," & _
                "  New addouble As disount)" & _
                "  RELATE productCode to productCode) AS COST)" & _
            "  RELATE zoneId to zoneId) As FECHAS", _
    "Provider=MSDataShape;Data Provider=None"
```

This code run and don't show error but in execution time don't show data and the query test work perfect. I'm making the report using the vb designer and the data's bind using DataField and DataMember names on an array.

Example:

```
rsCostumersZone.addNew Array("ZONEID", "ZONENAME"), (rsDataZone!tbz_id, rsDataZone!tbz_name)
```

I appreciate any hint on the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a messagebox between your load or set data source statement and 'Report.show' statement. I vaguely remember this issue. If it works you can then change the messagebox to something like DoEvents or Wait.